# JS cant call method drawImage of null

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I got this lil file

```
/* WaterBall API notification model by Makerimages*/
function WBNotification(x,y,icon,text)
{
this.background="/WBGraphics/WBNotification.png";
this.x=x;
this.y=y;
this.icon=icon;
this.text=text;






this.draw=function()
{

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.id="WBNotificationArea";
canvas.width=88;
canvas.height =43;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
cvs=document.getElementById("WBNotificationArea");
var context=cvs.getContext();
context.drawImage(this.background,this.x,this.y);
}
 return this;
}
```

and I use it like this

```
site=new waterContainer();
site.notifications[0]=new WBNotification(10,10,null,"hello there!");
site.notifications[0].draw()
```

everything works, but the this.draw() says(in chrome`s script reading thingy) that it cannot call method drawImage of null, how could I fix it?

Comment: `The getContext method returns null if the contextId value is not supported.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in the string `"2d"` to `getContext()`.

The function will return `null` if the context-type supplied is not available.

Comment: that makes it say Uncaught TypeError Type Error

Comment: What is `this` in your second chunk of code? Shouldn't it be `WBNotification.prototype`?

Comment: which line do you mean?

Comment: ??? is it the return line? if I set that to returning thw WbNotification.prototype, it says in the site... file that Object#<WBNotification> has no method "Draw"